# Unity2D move transform on touch

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch, transform

I want to move my main player as the user moves its mouse (on PC ) or finger (on mobile devices)
[image]

I made a simple illustration. If I move my finger 10 units in left, i want the player to move 10 units to the left as well. How can I achive this, for both mobile and PC ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Vector3 screenPoint;
Vector3 offset;

void OnMouseDown()
{
    screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
    offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
}

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
    Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint) + offset;
    transform.position = curPosition;
}
```

Add this code to your player's script.

Edit: This code is so simple to convert it to "move via click from every where". The only problem was OnMouse* functions works only when you click the scripted and collidered object. Just change it with Input.GetMouseButton and its solved.

```
bool flag = false;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        if (!flag)
        {
            flag = true;
            screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
            offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
        }

        Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
        Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint) + offset;
        transform.position = curPosition;
    }
    else
    {
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it will work only when i click the object i set the script to. It won't work if I click anywhere else on the screen.

Comment: you can use Input.GetMouseButton(0) instead of OnMouse* functions. I edited my answer you can look it

Answer (score 1):

You need two functions: `DragStart()` which you call on every mouse down, and `Drag()` which is called every frame the mouse stays down.

in the `DragStart()` method you want to first capture the mouse position into a variable named 'Vector2 mouseDown' and the other object position into a variable named `Vector2 objectStart`.

In the `Drag()` function you create a variable named `Vector2 offset` and basically you just do `offset = mouseDown - Input.mousePosition;` to get your offset, now all you have to do is move the other object by the same amount as your offset: `objectToMove.transform.localPosition = objectStart + offset`.